# Does the "Total number of records retrieved by SOQL queries" governor limit apply to sub-selects?

Tags: soql, governorlimits

I have a requirement to change the status of any `Contact` (master object) that has had a `Booking` (detail object) but not in the last 2 years to "Inactive":

```
Date d = Date.today().addYears(-2);
Contact[] contacts = [
        select Id
        from Contact
        where Status__c != 'Inactive'
        and Id in (select Client__c from Booking__c)
        and Id not in (select Client__c from Booking__c where LatestBookedDate__c > :d)
        ];
```

The org will have about 2,000 `Contact` objects but will end up with more than 50,000 `Booking` objects. In the content of the above code, I am wondering how this governor limit applies:

> Total number of records retrieved by SOQL queries 50,000

I assume/hope it only applies to the `Contact` object returned by the query and not to the sub-select `Booking` queries. (But perhaps [SOQL aggregate query limit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/7439/soql-aggregate-query-limit) implies the opposite.) Please clarify if you know.

(I'm not looking for alternative queries here, I'm looking to understand how the governor limit is applied.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to my knowledge Limit of 50k objects applies to each object query returns. So each element is counted as 1- no matter from query or nested query. Although list you used as filters (semi-join)are not returning any data and are not count against this limit.

```
There is no limit on the number of records matched in a subquery. 
Standard SOQL query limits apply to the main query.
```

Comment: Thanks. Googled that and its in http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/officetoolkit/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select.htm if anyone is interested in the context.

Answer (score 5):

## No

An Inner join / semi-join does not count against the [records retrieved limit of 50,000 records](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_gov_limits.htm).  However, there is not much (if any) documentation supporting this claim.  But, since we're coding, we can test this and see proof below.  **Note**: even though an inner join / semi-join doesn't count against `Limits.getQueryRows()`, it can impact query performance.

### Here's a proof:

```java
final Account account = new Account(
    Name = 'Test Account'
);
{
    insert account;
}   

final Contact[] contacts = new Contact[] {};
for(Integer i = 0; i < 200; i ++) {
    contacts.add(new Contact(
        LastName = 'Last-' + i, 
        AccountId = account.Id
    ));
}
{
    insert contacts;
}   

// Test 1: Query Accounts
{
    // Initial condition
    {
        System.assertEquals(0, Limits.getQueryRows());
    }   

    final Integer expected = 1; 

    final Account[] accounts = [
        SELECT Id
        FROM Account
        WHERE Id IN (
            SELECT AccountId
            FROM Contact
            WHERE Id IN :contacts
        )
    ];  

    final Integer actual = Limits.getQueryRows();  

    // Assert results are valid
    {
        System.assertEquals(1, accounts.size());
        System.assertEquals(account.Id, accounts[0].Id);
    }   

    // Assert actual equals expected
    {
        System.assertEquals(expected, actual);
    }
}   

// Test 2: Query Accounts with Contacts
{ 
    final Integer expected = Limits.getQueryRows() + 1 + contacts.size(); // Current Query Rows + Account + Contacts    

    final Account[] accounts = [
        SELECT 
            Id, 
            (
                SELECT Id
                FROM Contacts
            )
        FROM Account
        WHERE Id IN (
            SELECT AccountId
            FROM Contact
            WHERE Id IN :contacts
        )
    ];  

    final Integer actual = Limits.getQueryRows();  

    // Assert results are valid
    {
        System.assertEquals(1, accounts.size());
        System.assertEquals(account.Id, accounts[0].Id);
        System.assertEquals(contacts.size(), accounts[0].Contacts.size());
    }   

    // Assert actual equals expected
    {
        System.assertEquals(expected, actual);
    }
}

// Clean up data
{
    Database.delete(contacts);
    Database.emptyRecycleBin(contacts);

    Database.delete(account);
    Database.emptyRecycleBin(account);
}
```