# LWC's apex query returns more than 50k results, how to bypass this limitation?

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, query, limits

Any idea for how can I bypass this 50k row limitation?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: For future reference, you can use `![alt text][1]` ... `[1]: imageurl` to inline the images. I've done this for you this time.

Comment: Do you really need to present your users _50,000 rows_ in a data table? Why not just add a `LIMIT` clause substantially lower than 50,000?

Comment: @DavidReed I dont think its actually returning 50,000 rows, is it because the aggregrateresult is iterating over 50k rows?

Comment: So there aren't 50k rows of data presented to the user, it's just that we need to do calculations off these records, eg. using these to find out what the gross revenue is, etc. and that's the bit that we display to the end user. Is there any way I can query this? The odd thing is it works when I do it as a report (although it takes a while to load), but as a SOQL query it says "too many rows".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use your aggregate query in **for** loop and then add the result in the list.

Here **for** loop can process multiple batches of records by using internal calls to query and queryMore.

You can read more about it [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_VLSQ.htm).

Below is the code example for the same

```
List<AggregateResult> results =new List<AggregateResult>();
for (List<AggregateResult> agg: [select field__c from yourObject group by field__c ]){
    results.addAll(agg);
}
```

Also, you can go through this [thread](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/7439/soql-aggregate-query-limit-updated-for-summer18)

Comment: try to use results.addAll(agg); instead of results = agg;

Comment: Are you sure, if you are getting same value in dateTrade and partner variable as in Dev Console?

Comment: check the format you are getting in apex method by using system.debug(dateTraded) if they both are same.

Comment: I am really not sure what is the main issue but could you please try to replace your attribute with the static value you are using in your dev console and then test....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124975/discussion-between-shagun-sharma-and-user256515).